# Change parent of existing node that has children

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, ancestry

I am using rails 5 with ancestry gem. I have a Group model, and its records are already arranged in a tree. Now I pick up a group randomly which has children and try to change it's parent_id. The group object gets saved but the tree structure does not change as expected i.e. only one node gets moved not its children. Here is my code:

```
  def change_hierarchy(parent)
    if valid_move?(parent)
      self.parent_id= self.read_attribute(:parent_id) + '/' + parent.read_attribute(:parent_id)
      self.save
      true
    else
      false
    end
  end
```

Comment: What must `self.parent_id= self.read_attribute(:parent_id) + '/' + parent.read_attribute(:parent_id)` do? Did this method realy change position of any element? `ancestry` auto rebuild hierarchy and that code equal to `self.parent_id= self.read_attribute(:parent_id) ` because parent_id is int and `'id/some_id/other_id'.to_i == id`. So, that does nothing.

Comment: Why not just `self.update(parent_id: parent.parent_id`)? Also, there parameter `parent` overlaps attribute `parent` from `ancestry`.